# Source and target same verbiage not getting deployed using translation workbench

Tags: translation-workbench, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, chatbot

I am trying to deploy spanish translations using translation workbench

- i imported xlf file in the sandbox
- after successfully importing the file i can see that if english and spanish message verbiage are same then those translations are not getting deployed

Like we have a `Yes` `No` choice question for `No` choice ***english and spanish verbiage is same*** so for `No` message spanish translation are not getting deployed

Please let me know how we can deploy such type of translations